# java drools doesn't see excel sheet modifications

Tags: java, excel, drools

I am working with rule tables in a spring boot rest app. Hovever, it is as if the program has difficoulty seeing changes in the sheet. Whenever i change something and run the service again in eclipse, it still works with the old un-modified excel.

I know that because i have an error in one of my conditions and no matter how i fix it, it always displays the old expression, as it was before i changed it.  And there is no other expression in the entire excell.

anyone knows what is going on ?

Comment: Have you saved the sheet with the changes? Is there a write-delay to the harddrive - a caching effect?

Comment: Yes. I did. Ultimately, i managed to solve it. It turned out that this is the correct procedure - change excel, close and save excel, refresh project in eclipse, run project. Now it works properly. I have no idea why.